# separate the file in fileinputstream input and insert the data into oracle tables

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Currently i am reading the file input from where the file ending with `'gz'` and processing this input file data into my oracle tables.

Initially i was having only the files in the path which is ending with `'out.gz'` for example file name looks like `'xyz.out.gz'`. And the table name where i am inserting the data looks like `BB_xyz_IMPORT`.

But now i am also having the files in the same path which is ending with `'px.gz'` for example file name looks like `'xyz.px.gz'` and the table name where i am inserting the data looks like `BB_xyz_px_IMPORT`.

The table name conventions always looks like this so that it can differentiate the ending file name input data to insert between '`out.gz`' file and '`px.gz`' file.

So i want to modify my java code such that it should take the both the files appropriately, differantiate the file ending with `'out.gz'` and `'px.gz'` and insert this file data into correct oracle tables respectively.

Below is my java code. Currently the code is not recognizing the file name ending between '`out.gz`' file and '`px.gz`' and both the file is inserting the data in the same table for example which is '`BB_xyz_IMPORT`'.

```
    public class BIImportWorkflow extends AbstractBloombergWorkflow {
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BIImportWorkflow.class);

    @Override
    public boolean run(CommandLine commandLine) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = initializeApplicationContext();

        String inputFile = commandLine.getOptionValue("in");

        if (inputFile == null) {
            log.error("The input file has not been specified");
            return false;
        }

        log.info("Importiere Daten aus der Datei " + inputFile);

        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
                Reader underlyingReader = inputFile.endsWith("gz")
                        ? new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(is), DEFAULT_CHARSET)
                        : new InputStreamReader(is, DEFAULT_CHARSET);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(underlyingReader)) {

            BlImporter BlImporter = applicationContext.getBean(BlImporter.class);
            BlImporter.processFile(reader, tablenameFromFilename(inputFile));
        }
        log.info("Import abgeschlossen");

        return true;
    }

    private String tablenameFromFilename(String path) {
        String filename = Paths.get(path).getFileName().toString();
        return "BB_" + filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf('.')).toUpperCase() + "_IMPORT";
    }

    @Override
    public void addOptions(Options options) {
        options.addOption(null, "in", true, "(bbgimport) specifies the input file");
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "bbgimport";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateDatabase() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = initializeApplicationContext();
        BlDBMigrator BlDBMigrator = applicationContext.getBean(BlDBMigrator.class);
        BlDBMigrator.updateDB();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if/case statements"?

Comment: i have edited my question with more explanation and code. i mean i am not sure what conditions we can use to separate the file name ending with 'out.gz' and 'px.gz' so that it can insert the data correctly in the corresponding tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already wrote it :

```java
... inputFile.endsWith("gz") ? ... : ...;

boolean isIn = filePath.endsWith("px.gz");
boolean isOut = filePath.endsWith("out.gz");
```

So your method to get your table name :

```java
private String tablenameFromFilename(String path) {
  String filename = Paths.get(path).getFileName().toString();
  if (filename.endsWith("out.gz") {
     return "BB_"+ filename.substring(0,filename.indexOf('.')).toUpperCase() + "_IMPORT";
  } else if (filename.endsWith("px.gz")) {
    return "BB_" + filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf('.')).toUpperCase() + "_PX_IMPORT";
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Extension unsupported");
  }
}
```

Comment: i have edited my question with more explanation and code.

Comment: Updated to your problem